# Count values in first column where second column occurrences are the same in UNIX

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have to count values in first column of a file for which the second column occurrences are the same , using Unix.

```
12,abn

23,abn

45,hh

52,hh

89,mm

89,mm
```

My output should be something like this:

```
35,abn

97,hh

178,mm
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk -F, -vOFS=, 'NF{a[$2]+=$1}END{for(i in a) print a[i],i}' file | sort -n
35,abn
97,hh
178,mm
```